# AngularJS orderBy not working with groupBy

Tags: angularjs

I have this ng-repeater which looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in controller.collections.data | orderBy: '-plannedCollectionDate'">
        {{ item.plannedCollectionDate | date: 'fullDate' }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this works fine, it gets my data and orders it in reverse, but when I try this with the groupBy filter, the orderBy is ignored.
I tried it like this at first:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in controller.collections.data | groupBy: 'plannedCollectionDate' | orderBy: '-plannedCollectionDate'">

    {{ key | date: 'fullDate' }}

    <table class="table table-hover table-light">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="collection in value | filter: controller.filter" ng-click="controller.select(collection)" ng-class="{ active: controller.isSelected(collection), warning: collection.status.id === 2, success: collection.status.id === 4, danger: collection.status.id === 5 }">
                <td>
                    <div>{{ collection.supplierName }} {{ collection.description }}</div>
                    <div>to be collected by {{ collection.customerName }}</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a ui-sref=".collect({ selected: [collection]})">{{ collection.status.name }}</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="controller.delete(collection.id)">
                        <span class="fa fa-close"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

But it didn't work. After using google I found a solution that suggested this:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in controller.collections.data | groupBy: 'plannedCollectionDate' | toArray: true | orderBy: '-plannedCollectionDate'">

    {{ group.$key | date: 'fullDate' }}

    <table class="table table-hover table-light">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="collection in group | filter: controller.filter" ng-click="controller.select(collection)" ng-class="{ active: controller.isSelected(collection), warning: collection.status.id === 2, success: collection.status.id === 4, danger: collection.status.id === 5 }">
                <td>
                    <div>{{ collection.supplierName }} {{ collection.description }}</div>
                    <div>to be collected by {{ collection.customerName }}</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a ui-sref=".collect({ selected: [collection]})">{{ collection.status.name }}</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="controller.delete(collection.id)">
                        <span class="fa fa-close"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work either.
Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

the user group of `angular-filter` have written what needs to be done [here](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/issues/57#issuecomment-65041792)

example: `groupBy` returns an object but `orderBy` fiter expects an `array` ..so use `toArray:true` AND give `orderBy` an array to work with:

Controller:

```
$scope.objectToArray= function(arr) {  
    return $filter('objectToArray')
      ($filter('map')(arr, 'id'));
      }
```

View:
now`orderBy` can use `$scope.objectToArray` in your `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in controller.collections.data | groupBy: 'plannedCollectionDate' | toArray: true | orderBy: '-objectToArray'">
```

GL!